# What are the priorities/rules for pedestrian crossings without lights?

Tags: united-kingdom, traffic

On Euston Road in London there are several pedestrian crossings marked just by dots or little painted squares. They have no pedestrian lights, so do not seem to be covered by the bird obsessions (pelican, puffin, toucan, ..) in [The Highway Code](https://www.highwaycodeuk.co.uk/).

To me that means the pedestrians should follow the main traffic lights, ie. green means priority for the main road and pedestrian crossings, whereas vehicles turning off the main road should give way to pedestrians.

There are also some places where no lights are really visible for the pedestrians crossing, but the drivers seem to think they have priority.

Those cases may be examples of poorly designed junctions, but in either case, does anybody know what are the rules there?

Here's an example where Ossulton Road meets Euston. The crosswalk is marked with small white squares but there are no dedicated pedestrian signals. If the lights for Ossulston are red, who has priority? Pedestrians or cars/lorries turning from Euston into Ossulston?

Comment: Can you give a specific location? Do you mean the western side of Euston Road and Gordon Street as an example?

Comment: Where Chalton Street and Ossulston Street meet Euston Road, for example. Cars coming from Mabledon Place, turning left and then right into the latter appear to think they have priority, but there aren't really any visible lights for pedestrians there.

Comment: I tried to embed a picture from Google Maps of the Street View of Ossulston. Not sure if it'll come out.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see it. And sorry, it was Churchway in stead of Ossulston!